# Email Intermediary Between Sender and Receiver

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, web-applications, lambda, amazon-ses

I am using SES for emailing (currently only sending but I'm open to using it for receiving as well), EC2 server for web app and RDS. 
Web application written in Java.

I would like to act as intermediary for users that email each other through my website by having all emails sent between users go through me.

The purpose is to conceal the emails of the two users who are emailing each other.

I thought of doing something like this:
1) The initial email is sent on the website, there it receives a unique ID which is stored in the database (containing the email addresses of the sender and receiver).

2) All subsequent emails between the two users are sent to the website's email address with the unique ID appended as a label (eg:bob+[uniqueId]@domain.com).

3) The email is accordingly routed back and forth between receiver and sender (I perform minor modifications to the email).

(Airbnb does something similar when users of its site message each other).

An extra caveat is that I would like attachments to be able to be included in the emails as well (and thus, they would need to be forwarded).

Is this the correct way to implement this functionality?
Should I do it differently?
If this is the correct approach, any references for how to get started? Specifically, I'm not sure how to use a lambda function (if that is what I would be using) to send an email, or to query my RDS.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds similar to private email systems I've seen on other sites. I think you have the correct idea. I would recommend using SES for both sending and receiving, and use a Lambda function to process the incoming emails.

You can have SES fire a Lambda function when you receive an email: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-action-lambda-example-functions.html

The other option for triggering processing of incoming emails would be SES->SNS->Java application webhook. Or you could queue them up via SES->SNS->SQS and have your Java application subscribe to the SQS queue.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I am reading up on both options. Do you know of any advantages/disadvantages associated with the two options you presented? (since I am unfamiliar with both, any extra information will help me choose which option to use or what things to investigate further).

Comment: I used the second option: SES->SNS (to endpoint on server)->Java processing and forwarding of email

Comment: I was planning on using javamail to handle the emailing on my server. Do you have another/a better suggestion. I ask because I read this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#javamailserver

Comment: I thought you were using SES to handle sending and receiving email. Why would you need to run a separate mail server?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I misunderstood what running my own email server is. I was just having some trouble taking the email stored in S3 and sending it back out (the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` headers aren't being set appropriately). And I thought maybe there was something more appropriate than javamail to use for this.